# Is it possible to turn on and off airplane mode in android wear programmatically

Tags: wear-os, moto-360

Upto API level 16, it is possible to turn on/off airplane mode in Android devices. From API level of 17, it seems like the `Settings.Global`, which is read only has replaced the [`Settings.System`](http://dustinbreese.blogspot.in/2009/04/andoid-controlling-airplane-mode.html).

I want to know that, is it possible to turn on/off the airplane mode programmatically in android wear (Moto 360) which isn't rooted.

[image]
[image]

Comment: try this Settings.Global.putInt(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isAirplaneModeOn);

Comment: As I've already mentioned above, Settings.Global reads the settings, but it doesn't have write permission. I mean, I've tried and not working.

Comment: It's not possible anymore as you figured, for obvious security reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works properly on Rooted Device.

To Turn ON:

```
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Process process;
                    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c settings put global airplane_mode_on 1;am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

To Turn Off:

```
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                try {
                    Process process;
                    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c settings put global airplane_mode_on 0;am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, this works on rooted devices, but I want a solution for non rooted devices.